# Define agent with parameter (%) and delay time in main is based of it. (Anylogic)

Tags: random, parameters, simulation, anylogic

I have a simple model which has a separate Agent called 'Passenger'. Inside the Passenger I have a parameters called 'WITH_CHILDREN' which it's default value is randomTrue(0.5).

In my main process, I would like the Passenger that results TRUE for 'WITH_CHILDREN' to take longer at a specific delay process.

I thought it would be something like (inside the on enter action of the delay):

```
if(passenger.WITH_CHILDREN == true){

    delayTime = triangular(1,5,15);
else{
    delayTime = triangular(0,1,1.5);
}
```

However there are many errors with this :(
I would like to link it from the Agent as oppose to setting the percentage in the delay as I have future percentages parameters that will be used on other delays.... If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this directly in the delay time of the delay block using the following code:

```
agent.WITH_CHILDREN ?  triangular(1,5,15) : triangular(0,1,1.5)
```

And because an image is better than 1000 words (I made a mistake in the image... it's agent. not passenger.
[image: delay time magic]

when you use delayTime in the actions, it's only a readable variable, you can't change it.

And learn about the ? and : operators in java in here:
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Comment: Thanks Felipe! It worked great.
Is it the same for the pedestrian library too? In relation to a service time delay... I can't seem to locate the variable when dealing with the ped library... thoughts? 

Thanks again for initial answer! :D

Comment: wait, in fact i made a mistake in my answer...it's not passenger.WITH_CHILDREN it should be agent.WITH_CHILDREN and in the pedestrian library you use ped instead of agent

Comment: No worries Felipe, your solution made enough sense to me  I managed to figure it out. Can you call 'passenger.WITH_CHILDREN' if the agent is placed on the main process model (From the project hierarchy)?

Comment: if there is only unique passenger in the whole model, then yes... 

If you have a population then you will have to do passenger.get(i).WITH_CHILDREN where i is the index of the passenger... nevertheless to access that passenger, you need to add custom population in your source block and link it to the passenger population you have in main... a bit complicated

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Felipe. 
Final quick question - though I should probably post this a separate question. 
How you change the color of the 3D/2D model in the animation. Again, lets say, on the SOURCE process, in ON-EXIT, can I have a Java code saying:
    if(ped.WITH_CHILDREN == true){ changecolour; }

Comment: ped.setColor(red); 
or ped.setColor(randomColor());